# How can I manually interpolate string escapes in a Perl string?

Tags: perl, escaping, string-interpolation

In perl suppose I have a string like `'hello\tworld\n'`, and what I want is:

```
'hello  world
'
```

That is, "hello", then a literal tab character, then "world", then a literal newline. Or equivalently, `"hello\tworld\n"` (note the double quotes).

In other words, is there a function for taking a string with escape sequences and returning an equivalent string with all the escape sequences interpolated? I don't want to interpolate variables or anything else, just escape sequences like `\x`, where `x` is a letter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a problem that someone else would have [solved already](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::Escape). I've never used the module, but it looks useful:

```
use String::Escape qw(unbackslash);
my $s = unbackslash('hello\tworld\n');
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I found String::Interpolate, but that does something completely different.

Comment: Also, for people using this in Ubuntu 9.10, the version of String::Escape doesn't have `unbackslash`. Instead it has `unprintable`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with 'eval':

```
my $string = 'hello\tworld\n';
my $decoded_string = eval "\"$string\"";
```

Note that there are security issues tied to that approach if you don't have 100% control of the input string.

Edit: If you want to ONLY interpolate \x substitutions (and not the general case of 'anything Perl would interpolate in a quoted string') you could do this:

```
my $string = 'hello\tworld\n';
$string =~ s#([^\\A-Za-z_0-9])#\\$1#gs;
my $decoded_string = eval "\"$string\"";
```

That does almost the same thing as quotemeta - but exempts '\' characters from being escaped.

Edit2: This still isn't 100% safe because if the last character is a '\' - it will 'leak' past the end of the string though...

Personally, if I wanted to be 100% safe I would make a hash with the subs I specifically wanted and use a regex substitution instead of an eval:

```
my %sub_strings = (
    '\n' => "\n",
    '\t' => "\t",
    '\r' => "\r",
);

$string =~ s/(\\n|\\t|\\n)/$sub_strings{$1}/gs;
```

Comment: Can I use a combination of `eval` and `quotemeta` to do this safely? Basically, `(my $interpolated_string = eval(q(") . quotemeta($string) . q("))) =~ s/\\(.)/\1/g`.

Comment: Not without it killing the interpolation as well. ;)

Comment: Well, I only want to interpolate `\x`, where `x` is any letter. Not variables or other stuff.