# How do I convert escaped characters into actual special characters in Perl?

Tags: perl, escaping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I manually interpolate string escapes in a Perl string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660123/how-can-i-manually-interpolate-string-escapes-in-a-perl-string)

I'm reading a string from a particular file. The problem with it is that it contains escaped characters, like:

```
Hello!\nI\'d like to tell you a little \"secret\"...
```

I'd like it to be printed out without escape sequences, like:

```
Hello!
I'd like to tell you a little "secret".
```

I thought about removing single backslashes and replacing double with single (since \ is represented as \\), but that doesn't help me with the \n, \t issues and so on. Before trying to fiddle with ugly, complex replace strings I thought I'd ask - maybe Perl has a built-in mechanism for such transformation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Perl single character [backslash escapes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html), you can do this safely using a two character `eval` as part of the substitution. You need to put in the characters that are acceptable to interpret in the character class after the `\`, and then the single character after is `eval`'d and inserted into the string.

Consider:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

print "\n\n\n\n";

while (my $data = <DATA>) {
    $data=~s/\\([rnt'"\\])/"qq|\\$1|"/gee;
    print $data;
}

__DATA__
Hello!\nI\'d like to tell you a little \"secret\".
A backslask:\\
Tab'\t'stop
line 1\rline 2  (on Unix, "line 1" will get overwritten)
line 3\\nline 4 (should result in "line 3\\nline 4")
line 5\r\nline 6
```

Output:

```
Hello!
I'd like to tell you a little "secret".
A backslask:\
Tab'    'stop
line 2  (on Unix, "line 1" will get overwritten)
line 3\nline 4 (should result in "line 3\nline 4")
line 5
line 6
```

The line `s/\\([rnt'"\\])/"qq|\\$1|"/gee` does the work.

- The `\\([rnt'"\\])` has the acceptable characters to eval inside the braces.
- The `gee` part does a double eval on the replacement string.
- The `"qq|\\$1|"` part is eval'd twice. The first `eval` replaces `$1` into the string, and the second performs the interpolation.

I cannot think of a two character combination here that would be a security breach...

This method does *not* deal with the following properly:

- Quoted strings. For example, Perl would not unescape the string 'line 1\nline 2' because of the single quotes.
- Escapes sequences that are longer than a single character, such as hex `\x1b` or Unicode such as `\N{U+...}` or control sequences such as `\cD`
- Anchored escapes, such as \LMAKE LOWER CASE\E or \Umake upper case\E

If you want more complete escape replacement, you can use this regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

print "\n\n\n\n";

binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

while (my $data = <DATA>) {
    $data=~s/\\(
        (?:[arnt'"\\]) |               # Single char escapes
        (?:[ul].) |                    # uc or lc next char
        (?:x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}) |          # 2 digit hex escape
        (?:x\{[0-9a-fA-F]+\}) |        # more than 2 digit hex
        (?:\d{2,3}) |                  # octal
        (?:N\{U\+[0-9a-fA-F]{2,4}\})   # unicode by hex
        )/"qq|\\$1|"/geex;  
    print $data;
}

__DATA__
Hello!\nI\'d like to tell you a little \"secret\".
Here is octal: \120 
Here is UNICODE: \N{U+0041} and \N{U+41} and \N{U+263D}
Here is a little hex:\x50 \x5fa \x{5fa} \x{263B}
lower case next char \lU \lA
upper case next char \ua \uu
A backslask:\\
Tab'\t'stop
line 1\rline 2  (on Unix, "line 1" will get overwritten)
line 3\\nline 4 (should result in "line 3\\nline 4")
line 5\r\nline 6
```

That handles all Perl [escapes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html) except:

1. Anchored type (\Q, \U, \L ended by \E)
2. Quoted forms, such as `'don't \n escape in single quotes'` or `[not \n in here]`
3. named unicode characters, such as `\N{THAI CHARACTER SO SO}`
4. Control characters like `\cD` (that is easily added...)

But that was not part of your question as I understood it...

Answer (score 3):

I hate to suggest this, but string `eval` would solve the problem, but string `eval` brings up a host of security and maintenance issues.  Where does this data come from?  Are there any contracts between the producers of data and you about what the string will hold?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $input = <DATA>) {
    #note: this only works if # is not allowed as a character in the string
    my $string = eval "qq#$input#" or die $@;
    print $string;
}

__DATA__
Hello!\nI\'d like to tell you a little \"secret\".
This is bad @{[print "I have pwned you\n"]}.
```

The other solution is to create a hash that defines all of the escapes you want to implement and do a substitution.

Comment: It's a local application, a command line script, used to parse logfiles from some other utility. In that case I think eval wouldn't be that much of a security breach, right?

Comment: Are you eval'ing what is in the log files?  If so, how did the data get in the log file?  If all a user has to do is craft the right message to break or compromise your code, then they will.  A better option would be to fix whoever is writing the log files to use a standardized method of escaping special characters like the one in RFC 3986 (i.e. URI escaping).