# Perl Force Inteprolation of Literal String

Tags: string, perl, literals

I have a Scalar variable that is assigned a literal string value via assignment to a hash value. I.e.

```
my $value = $configHash{'key'};
```

The value associated with that key are the three characters `~\n`.

When I print `$value` it prints the literal interpretation of the value:

```
print $value

Outputs: ~\n

Want: ~ <followed by a newline>
```

Is there any way I can force the print statement to treat the string as a doubly quoted string and not a literal?

I attempted these with no success:

```
print "$value$";
print qq($value);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660123/how-can-i-manually-interpolate-string-escapes-in-a-perl-string

Comment: How is `$configHash{key}` set in the first place? That's really where the interpolation should happen: `$configHash{key} = "~\n";`

Comment: You need to show how the hash key is being set as ThisSuitIsBlackNot said. This works:

perl -e '$h{'k'}="~\n"; $a=$h{'k'}; print $a;'

Comment: The hash key is being set via a module that reads data out of a python-style dictionary file. I have changed the code in this module to double interpolate the inputs via the method here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=12275